# Subgroup generated by n-th powers of elements

Tags: group-theory

How can I prove that, if we have a group G, then subgroup of G generated by all n-th powers of elements from G is normal subgroup of G?

Comment: Question: Is G abelian ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be

Comment: Should the set of all nth powers be a group ?

Comment: No @Amr, it shouldn't, but that's why Martin wrote about the subgroup *generated* by the n-th powers.

Comment: This is what I assumed. At the beginning, I thought that he wanted me to prove that its a subgroup

Answer (score 5):

Not only a normal subgroup but in fact a [fully invariant](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Fully_invariant_subgroup) subgroup , since for any endomorphism $\,\phi:G\to G\,$ ,we have:

$$\forall\,x\in G\,\,\,,\,\,\phi (x^n)=(\phi x)^n\Longrightarrow \phi(G^n)\subset G^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$yx^ny^{-1}=(yxy^{-1})^n$

Comment: I assumeed that the set $H=${$x^n|x$ is in G} is a group. Now it suffices to show that for all y in G $yHy^{-1}$ is a subset of H

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot :)